# Migrate from powerbuilder 12.5.2 version to powerbuilder 2017,espcially using EAServer in the application?

Tags: powerbuilder

What will be required to migrate from powerbuilder 12.5.2 to powerbuilder 2017,espcially using EAServer in the application?SQL Server using as the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get rid of EAServer in order to upgrade to PowerBuilder 2017.  The reason is that SAP is no longer continuing development of this product, and so this feature has been discontinued from PowerBuilder 2017 and newer versions.  This discontinued feature and other migration considerations are documented in the migration guide: https://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/pb2017r3/migrating_pb_apps/

There are two options to move forward, which both relate to getting rid of EAServer:

1. Move all your EAServer NVOs back to the client-side (as PowerScript NVOs).
2. Port your EAServer NVOs to C# Web APIs (running on IIS or Kestrel) with PowerBuilder 2019's new C# migration solution: https://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/pb2019/whats_new/ch02s01.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments.There are lot of EA server dependencies for this project.Which is the best way to get rid of EA sever?Moving all NVOs to C# Web APIs is time consuming and will take lot of efforts?